# Stuck in screen saver during upgrade

Tags: upgrade, screensaver

I'm upgrading from a LTS version to an other. The screen saver is now on and I can't exit it.

If I type my password or move the mouse the screen flickers. Regardless of what I do the screen saver stays and the login prompt never shows. If I type my password and then hit enter, it does nothing.

Last time I checked the packages were all downloaded and I was in the install process.

I really want this upgrade to work. It would be really bad to have to restart from a fresh install.

Cheers.

Comment: ctrl+alt+delete or alt+f1 does nothing.

Comment: shoul'd I let it run for a couple of hours to see what will happen or I'm wasting my time?

Comment: This question was ridiculous when thinking of it afterwards but nevertheless I've been troubled for a least 30 minutes wanting to fix the issue without compromising the upgrade. That's why I thought that I should document it so if it happens to another user there will be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press CTRL-ALT-F1 to enter console.

```
ps ax|grep screen
```

kill -9 all screensaver related task.

CTRL+ALT+F7 to retrun to gnome desktop.